# Grid layout with column width depending on children

Tags: css, css-grid

I imagine there is a simple way to do this, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a container that's `display: grid`, and all I need is:

- if there are one or two children, it should have two columns
- if there are more than two children, it should have three columns

I don't want to do with some logic that checks the number of children (I'm using emotion, by the way). There must be a way to do it with widths, `grid-template-columns`, etc.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid-auto-columns` co-jointly with `grid-template-colums` to have a minimum set amount of columns with more being added if there are enough children.

Comment: This sounds promising. Can you elaborate, perhaps with an example?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman https://codepen.io/Wolfeur/pen/eYKjwNo

Comment: Thanks but I need the max number of columns per row to be 3. Your solution handles the minimum cases (1 item, 2 items = 2 columns ✔) and of course 3 items = 3 columns; but any more than 3 items needs to result in rows of 3 columns each.

Comment: Then I believe your best bet is to use `:has`, but the support isn't completely there yet.